# loop and return a number for an ID

Tags: javascript, loops

I need to create multiple objects, and each one must have an ID.

All of them will be inside an Array.

So it will look like this:

```
const array = [
{
  id: 1,
  bla: "bla"
},
{
  id: 2,
  bla: "bla"
},
{
  id: 3,
  bla: "bla"
}
]
```

my question is, Is there a way to create a function, the will return a number that i can put inside those id's?

Comment: `getNextId(arr) =>arr.length + 1`

Comment: @tymeJV hey man thanks, but sorry i dont really get it and cant find to much info online about getnextid.
can you be more specific?

Comment: What do you want the number to be?  `index + 1` as you are showing?

Answer (score 1):

```
function makeArrayWithId(...objects) {
    return objects.map((o, i) => ({ id: i + 1, ...o }))
}


const arr = makeArrayWithId(
    {
        bla: "bla"
    },
    {
        bla: "bla"
    },
    {
        bla: "bla"
    },
)

console.log(arr)
```

it will prints:

```
[ { id: 1, bla: 'bla' }, { id: 2, bla: 'bla' }, { id: 3, bla: 'bla' } ]
```

if you already have an array that each object has no id, you can pass it to this function like this:

```
let myArr = [
    {
        bla: 'bla'
    },
    {
        bla: 'bla'
    },
    {
        bla: 'bla'
    },
]
myArrr = makeArrayWithId(...myArr)
console.log(myArr)
```

it will prints:

```
[ { id: 1, bla: 'bla' }, { id: 2, bla: 'bla' }, { id: 3, bla: 'bla' } ]
```

Comment: look almost perfect, but it returns
[ {bla: "bla"}, {bla: "bla"} {bla: "bla"}, {bla: "bla"} id: 1 ]
thanks you for your answer! maybe its a misprint?

Comment: @bigLezo sorry you are right. I edited my answer. I forgot to put ... before function parameter when call it. please try again based on my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You likely want what we call generators/iterators.

An generator/iterator is a function that has an inner state.

In js, it's created by adding an "*" next to the "function" and using "yield" keyword instead of "return" (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield).

When the generator is called, it saves the arguments it was given and returns an iterator, on which you can call .next() to get the next value (note an object with "value" attribute is returned).

```
function* idGenerator (startingIndex) {
    while (true){
        //the iterator will keep his inner state
        startingIndex += 1;
        yield startingIndex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [
{
  bla: "bla"
},
{
  bla: "bla"
},
{
  bla: "bla"
}
]


array = array.map((item, index) => Object.assign({}, item, { id: index + 1 }))
```

Output:

```
[ { bla: 'bla', id: 1 },
  { bla: 'bla', id: 2 },
  { bla: 'bla', id: 3 } ]
```